# Displaying a specific collection in Shopify

Tags: shopify

Hi I'm coding a psd to be a Shopify theme. The actual shop is supposed to have several collections of products.  I've also new to shopify.

Here's what I'm not sure about.   I'll have a top nav listing the various collections....women's dresses, Men's shirts etc.  but what's the best coding practice or technique to ensure the right collections get's displayed on the single collections page (collections.liquid) when the user clicks through each time.

This demo achieves what I'm explaining and I've downloaded the theme and studied the source code but still don't really understand.

http://megatronic-theme.myshopify.com/collections

(click the category links in the left hand nav and the one page display the relevant collection each time)

I was hoping someone could explain in simple terms the coding process.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is done for you automatically. Shopify will pick up on the collection specified in the url (e.g. `blah.myshopify.com/collections/hello`) and drop that collection (`hello` in our example) into the `collection` liquid variable. You can then access the products using `collection.products` in the template

Here's the relevant documentation (A bit sparse, I'll admit) showing you the variables that are available within the `collection.liquid` template: http://wiki.shopify.com/Collection.liquid

Answer (score 0):

**/collections** path is using `list-collection.liquid` template, if you want to change the default behavior, then edit that file.

By default it shows all collections from shop, it can be as automatic collections and as the manual created ones.